# Middleware functionality in Next.js 13.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, middleware

I really struggled the whole day, at last, I came to an end to share my problem with you so you as a professional developer, resolve my problem. so, I'm having a problem getting Next Auth token that was provided by my instructor, so according to him, he was using next js 12 version, which was updated right now, he just created a folder called middleware folder and just created auth.js and his file is:
middleware/auth.js:

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
export async function middleware(req: any,res:any) {
  const token = await getToken({
    req,
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    secureCookie: process.env.NODE_ENV == "production",
  });
  if (token) {
    //signed in?
    req.user = token.sub;
    return NextResponse.next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "Not signed in: " });
  }
  res.end();

}
```

Since i'm new with next js i followed articles and found that next js upgraded. so What I want is to get this middleware code here but with latest next js 13.4.

Comment: What does not work ? What errors do you see ? -- Are all environment variables set ? Is [`NEXTAUTH_URL`](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#using-gettoken) set ? See also [next-auth / nextjs middleware](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware)